# Chef: Process sequence in a recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

my question is to verify the processes in my cookbook.

My test is with 
Chef 12.18.31
Ubuntu 16.04 - AWS EC2 - Opsworks Stack

So, if I have a recipe with a sequence like this:

```
Native_Chef_Resource do
Chef::Log.info("First")
My_First_Variable
end

My_Command do
my script based on My_First_Variable
end

My_Resource do
Chef::Log.info("Second")
My_Second_Variable
end

My_Other_Command do
my script based on My_Second_Variable
end
```

I noticed that the native chef resource is executed in time to have value into My_Command, but the resources that I create into my cookbook don't respect ever the sequence and I don't have the value in My_Other_Command.

After this doubt, I tryied "Notifies" with these recipe and resource.

**Recipe**

```
test 'test notify' do
par_test 'primo test'
notifies :run, 'execute[bo]', :immediately
end

execute 'bo' do
command 'echo uname -a'
Chef::Log.info("execute bo")
end
```

**Resource**

```
resource_name :test
property :par_test
default_action :create
action :create do
Chef::Log.info("#{par_test}")
end
```

I made two test, one with 'immediately' and other with 'before'.

The results:

Test with immediately
*[2017-10-15T12:54:41+02:00] INFO: execute bo
[2017-10-15T12:54:41+02:00] INFO: Processing test[test notify] action create (deploy::test_notify line 1)
[2017-10-15T12:54:41+02:00] INFO: primo test
[2017-10-15T12:54:41+02:00] INFO: Processing execute[bo] action run (deploy::test_notify line 6)
[2017-10-15T12:54:41+02:00] INFO: execute[bo] ran successfully*

Test with before

*[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: execute bo
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: test[test notify] running why-run create action to support before action
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: Processing test[test notify] action create (deploy::test_notify line 1)
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: primo test
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: Processing test[test notify] action create (deploy::test_notify line 1)
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: primo test
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: Processing execute[bo] action run (deploy::test_notify line 6)
[2017-10-15T13:16:31+02:00] INFO: execute[bo] ran successfully*

What do you think about sequence of executions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a longer description of this at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ but basically:

Any Ruby code in a recipe at the base level (which includes all the calls to create resources) is run when the recipe file is compiled. This includes any code in in the main `do ... end` block of the resource (as opposed to the `block` property of `ruby_block` or anything inside `lazy{}`) as that block is `instance_eval`'d during the creation of the resource object. The action method for a resource is run during the converge phase, after all recipes in the run list are compiled. This process is repeated in a recursive way for custom resources, who's action methods are their own mini compile and converge phases.